# Redirecting app to webpage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So i'm making this app for Windows Phone 8, and what it basically does is redirect to a webpage, how do I do so? Because what I did is add the code and when I start the app, it redirects to the browser and webpage, but if i press the back button, it goes back to the blank "MainPage.xaml". How do I remove the main page from appearing? Such as once the browser is launched, the app auto-quits

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/html) control (the default when you use the Windows Phone HTML 5 App template). In this case, you're not redirecting, you're hosting the browser as part of your app, and can then also take advantage of other platform features within the app.
2. Use [Application.Current.Terminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.application.terminate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in Windows Phone 8. For instance, the following opens the app, immediately starts up the browser, and then quits the XAML app leaving the browser on the screen.

   ```
   // Constructor
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.cnn.com", UriKind.Absolute));
       Application.Current.Terminate();
   }
   ```

Though this is possible, it doesn't seem all that useful and I'm doubtful it would pass certification since all it does is launch a browser (but I'm presuming this is just part of where you're going with this app?)